# How does youtube do video quality change/video compression?

Tags: algorithms, approximation, information-theory, data-compression

After uploading a high definition video in youtube, youtube automatically makes a low definition(standard definition) version of the video.
I would like to know what algorithm they use to reduce the quality of video. Is it lossless or lossy?

If not youtube, I would like to know what algorithms are there in the literature that does this?

Comment: The algorithm is lossy, since you can tell the difference. You might be interested in the following question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-compression-does-YouTube-use-to-store-videos.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the research paper/reference to learn the algorithm?

Comment: I'm sure you can find it yourself. It's a pretty standard algorithm.